# SSL certificate GlassFish

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish

I want to set SSL certificate on `GlassFish`. I follow by this [Controller SSL and Certificates](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO41/Controller+SSL+and+Certificates) link

I actually have .cer file and I used that commands:

```
keytool -delete -alias s1as -keystore keystore.jks

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias s1as -file xxx.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

In `keystore.jks` s1as has new certificate fingerprint. After restart `glassfish` server https://yyy:8181/zzz/ not working.

Why? What I do wrong or what I didn't do? Changing master-password is important?

Comment: The page doesn't load up - "the webpage is not available".